# Spring How to redirect when button clicked and how to print to console when another button clicked?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class StoreController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addProduct")
    public String addProduct() {
        return "addProduct";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/print")
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Printed");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/redirectToAddProd")
    public String redirectToAddProd() {
        return "redirect:addProduct";
    }
}
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Store</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="addProduct.html">Add new product</a>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/redirectToAddProd}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my addProduct.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add a product</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/print}">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My store-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ecommerce.store" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/static/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And finally my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MyStore</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>store</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>store</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/addProduct.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

So, I got two problems.

1. In index.html, why the href method works and the button method redirecting does not work?
2. In addProduct.html how can I print to the console when button pressed?

Thankyou guys, hope you can help me.

EDIT:
Hey guys, I discovered onde thing. My problem could be with Tomcat.
I don't know why but sometimes my Tomcat is not deploying.
In my index.html I add a new button for example, publish to the server, run the server and the button is not appearing. Do someone know any solution to this? I disabled auto deploy (but with auto deploy not working to).
And I'm running on Spring Tool Suit (eclipse)
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The cache problem can be because of thymeleaf cache configuration.

To disable cache with xml config:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <!-- Others configs here ... -->
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

To disable cache with java config:

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    // Others configs here ... 
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

    return templateResolver;
}
```

Ps: Only disable cache in the development environment.

Comment: Thank you, this one I can only confirm with time because is a bit random. Sometimes loads right and other times loads the cached page.

Comment: There is only one problem with your xml config. The property name is "cacheable" and not "cache". Besides that, is working very well. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, after all it continues loading cached page.

Answer (score 1):

Found out my problem. Tomcat is deploying well but when I open the page the browser load the cached page.